# How to refence entries with a certain value within a list in python

Tags: python, list, raspberry-pi

I am getting data from database and storing it in a list called relays. this list currently looks like this:

```
 relay:  [(4, '26', '19'), (5, '13', '6')]
```

the first number of each item is the id number I use through out the code. the second two are numbers GPIO pins .

I want a away to reference the list item by it's first number so for instance variable[5][1] which would return 13.  so to turn on this GPO pin I can just run something like:

```
GPIO.output(variable[5][1], True)
GPIO.output(variable[4][2], True)
```

Is this possible? (sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to python)

Comment: you mean like a dictionary? `variable = {4: (4, '26', '19'), 5: (5, '13', '6')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dict with first value of tuple as a key and the whole tuple as value:

```
relay =  [(4, '26', '19'), (5, '13', '6')]

# desired = {4: (4, '26', '19'), 5: (5, '13', '6')} 

# dict with first tup val as key and the whole tup as val
variable = {x[0]: (x) for x in relay}  

print(variable)

# print the dict with key `5` and then the first (1) index val of tup
print(variable[5][1])
```

OUTPUT:

```
{4: (4, '26', '19'), 5: (5, '13', '6')}                                                                                                                                      
13
```

Comment: Did you mean `variable = {x[0]: (x) for x in relay}; print(variable)`?

Comment: @quamrana very much, added with clarity! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionaries in python (`dict`)

Initialize it like this:

```
variable = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in relay}
```

note that here, to access `'13'` like your example, you need to write `variable[5][0]`